# C++ unit testing with Microsoft MFC

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mfc

I'm trying to convince my organization to start running unit tests on our C++ code. This is a two-part question:

1. Any tips on convincing my employer that unit testing saves money in the long run? (They have a hard time justifying the immediate expenses.)
2. I'm not familiar with any C++ testing frameworks that integrate well with MFC. Does anyone have experience with this, or use any general test harnesses that could be extended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer the second question - the Boost Test framework can be used with MFC and someone has posted an excellent article about it on Code Project:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/Designing_Robust_Objects.aspx

Answer (score 1):

[Tut](http://tut-framework.sourceforge.net/) framework isn't bad and very clear.

For the first part of the question :

1. Faster time to market
2. Higher code quality
3. More flexibility

Have a look [here](http://www.agitar.com/solutions/why_unit_testing.html). It could be help you to find statements for

Answer (score 1):

Boost test is really complete, but a little cumbersome.

If you just want to make simple tests, spending as little time as possible, have a look at [google test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/).